# How would i check if e.item is the same as an object in a collectionviewsource?

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, xaml, mvvm

I want to check if e.Item is the same as any object in a collectionviewsource, and if they are, they get accepted.

```
namespace Planteskole.WPF.Views
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for HomeView.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class HomeView : UserControl
    {
        private readonly PlantContext _context = new PlantContext();

        private CollectionViewSource PlantViewSource;
        private CollectionViewSource AreaViewSource;
        private CollectionViewSource LocationViewSource;

        public HomeView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            PlantViewSource = (CollectionViewSource)FindResource(nameof(PlantViewSource));
            AreaViewSource = (CollectionViewSource)FindResource(nameof(AreaViewSource));
            LocationViewSource = (CollectionViewSource)FindResource(nameof(LocationViewSource));
        }

        private void Grid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //_context.Database.EnsureDeleted();

            _context.Database.EnsureCreated();

            _context.Plants.Load();
            _context.Areas.Load();
            _context.Locations.Load();

            PlantViewSource.Source = _context.Plants.Local.ToObservableCollection();
            AreaViewSource.Source = _context.Areas.Local.ToObservableCollection();
            LocationViewSource.Source = _context.Locations.Local.ToObservableCollection();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _context.SaveChanges();

            PlantDataGrid.Items.Refresh();
        }

        private void CollectionViewSource_Filter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
        {
            
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                if ((e.Item as Area).Id == 20)
                {
                    e.Accepted = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    e.Accepted = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="PlantViewSource"/>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="AreaViewSource"/>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="LocationViewSource" Filter = "CollectionViewSource_Filter"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid Loaded="Grid_Loaded" Margin="10">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListBox Grid.Row="0" x:Name="PlantDataGrid" ItemsSource ="{Binding Source={StaticResource AreaViewSource}}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Expander Header="{Binding Name}">
                        <ListBox ItemsSource ="{Binding Source={StaticResource LocationViewSource}}">
                            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Expander Header="{Binding Name}">
                                        <Grid>
                                            <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" 
                                                    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource PlantViewSource}}" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" 
                                                    RenderTransformOrigin="0.488,0.251">
                                                <DataGrid.Columns>
                                                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Id}" Header="Id" Width="auto" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                                                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name" Width="auto"/>
                                                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Amount}" Header="Amount" Width="auto"/>
                                                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Sellable}" Header="Sellable" Width="*"/>
                                                </DataGrid.Columns>
                                            </DataGrid>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Expander>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListBox>
                    </Expander>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Save" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0 10" Click="Button_Click" Height="20" Width="124"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The end result should be that if the Id of a column in the area table is the same as the value "areaid" in the location table in the database, the location would get shown under that area.

I'm new here so i don't know if i should put all my code in the post or not. Feel free to correct me and thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use [IEnumerable.Any](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any) like `e.Accepted = AreaViewSource.Any(a => ((Area)a).Id == ((Area)e.Item).Id)`

Comment: When i try that it tells me AreaViewSource does not contain a definition for "any"
And if i replace AreaViewSource with _context.Areas i get the following error
InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Planteskole.Domain.Models.Location' to type 'Planteskole.Domain.Models.Area'.

Comment: You branch the event filter of `LocationViewSource` to the method `CollectionViewSource_Filter`, but in this method you cast to `Area`... It's inconsistent.

Comment: @LukasJensen: Why don't you use navigation properties? A `Location` should have a `Plants` property that you can bind to directly.